# ASP.NET Kendo UI grid calculate columns

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I have a grid and I want to calculate the column. Here is the code I have to calculate the total column

```
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)    
  .Name("Grid")
  .Columns(columns =>
  {
      columns.Bound(p => p.ProductId).Groupable(false);
      columns.Bound(p => p.ProductName);
      columns.Bound(p => p.UnitPrice);
      columns.Bound(p => p.Quantity);
      columns.Bound(p => p.Tax);
      columns.Bound(p => p.Total).ClientTemplate("#= calculate() #");

  })
  .Groupable()
  .Pageable()
  .Sortable()
  .Scrollable()
  .Filterable()
  .Editable(e=>e.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))

  .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
      .Ajax()
      .Read(read => read.Action("Products_Read", "Product")) 
      .PageSize(20)
      .Model(model =>
      {
          model.Id(p => p.ProductId);
          model.Field(p => p.ProductName);
          model.Field(p => p.UnitPrice);
          model.Field(p => p.Quantity);
          model.Field(p => p.Tax);


      })


  ))
```

I want to calculate the last column.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with the following template :) :

```
#= UnitPrice*Tax #
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to calculate at runtime, handle Grid *Change* event and use the solution here: [Kendo Asp.net MVC Grid Batch Mode Calculated Column Display does not update](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24052947/2020512)